# SQL parameter overflows in varchar(20) column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have code where a 12 digit numeric ID is used in a table.

```
string sql = "SELECT * " +
             "  FROM table" +
             "  WHERE ID = @id";
            
using (IDbTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    data = con.Query<ModelDapper.Model.Table>(sql, new { ID = id }, transaction, true, SQLConnection.CommandTimeout, null).ToList();

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

In code, `ID` is a string, in table `ID` of datatype `varchar(20)`.

How would I ensure that `@id` is seen as `varchar(20)` and not as integer by SQL Server? As this is a legacy project, I'd prefer the change as few things as possible.

Comment: *"How would I ensure, that @id is seen as varchar(20) and not as string by the sql server?"* A `varchar(20)` *is* a string.

Comment: of course ... i meant integer

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `ReadUncommitted`? Are you ok with the results being accurate most of the time while other times it may return missing and/or duplicate rows?

Comment: I just want to fix the bug with the overflow

Comment: @SeanLange `ReadCommitted` can also return missing rows and/or duplicate rows. It's not a problem. So lets not focus on things that a) aren't problems, b) aren't part of the question.

Comment: @IanBoyd got any links where that is discussed?

Comment: @SeanLange No, but i'll tell you how to reproduce it. Perform `SELECT * FROM Orders`. SQL Server will take shared locks as it scans the table, releasing them as it goes. Then say the server is halfway through scanning the table, when another process performs an update the causes the row's physical order to now come at the end. When the `SELECT *` finally reaches that page, it will put a shared lock on the page, read the (duplicate) row, and return it. Same goes for missing rows. You can reproduce it in SSMS with some infinite loops, updating and selecting.

Comment: If you want to prevent it, you need SQL Server to keep it's shared read-only page locks for the duration of the entire scan: which is "repeatable read". Read Committed means you don't see *uncommitted* changes. But if the change as been committed, you can get the row again in your scan, or not at all.

Comment: @IanBoyd interesting. Will have to do some tests on that. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanLange I did it years ago to prove to myself it was impossible - as i was getting an impossible bug in production. It's not impossible. It happens all the time. It is **repeatable read** that will continue to lock rows it has already read, ensuring nobody else can move them during my SELECT (and killing concurrency).  And it is `serializable` that will not only hold locks on rows its already read, but also hold a lock that prevents any new rows from being inserted that match my search criteria.

Comment: Is there a problem you've experiencing, Murf? If `id` variable is a `String`, and the `ID` column is a `varchar`, then it will be treated as a string, and inserted as a string. Is something not treating it as a string? Is something not inserting it as a string?

Comment: @SeanLange https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/read-committed-isolation-level/ba-p/383258

Comment: Though the phenomena is more likely with `NOLOCK` (as well as obvious possibility of dirty reads and "could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement" error)

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
WHERE ID = cast(@id as varchar(20))
```

Comment: that simple? now i feel stupid for asking. i will try thank, thank you

Answer (score 6):

You could explicitly set your parameter type in your calling code:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@ID", id, DbType.AnsiString, ParameterDirection.Input, 20);
data = con.Query<ModelDapper.Model.Table>(sql, parameters, transaction, true, SQLConnection.CommandTimeout, null).ToList();
```

Or you could convert the parameter within SQL:

```
string sql = "SELECT * " +
         "  FROM table" +
         "  WHERE ID = CAST(@id AS VARCHAR(20))";
```

Answer (score 2):

The DbType.AnsiString is used to explicitly specify that the parameter @id should be treated as a varchar, and the size: 20 parameter ensures that the correct size is set for the varchar.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = @id";

using (IDbTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@id", id, DbType.AnsiString, size: 20); // Specify DbType.AnsiString and size: 20

    data = con.Query<ModelDapper.Model.Table>(sql, parameters, transaction, true, SQLConnection.CommandTimeout, null).ToList();

    transaction.Commit();
}
```